# Give attributes to an agent in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am in the process of making a line of the subway, I have the station agents and pedestrian street and I'm trying to do to assign the origin station, pedSource where the passenger is created, and that you will randomly assign a random destination station of the other remaining.
To this end, I have created this function:

```
Estacion myEstacion = this.get_Estacion();
int countConnectedEstaciones = myEstacion.getConnectionsNumber();
int randomConnecteEstacionIndex = uniform_discr(0, countConnectedEstaciones - 1);

Estacion estacionDestino =(Estacion) myEstacion.getConnectedAgent(randomConnecteEstacionIndex);

traceln(this + "just moved from Station " +myEstacion+  " to "+ estacionDestino );
```

But it doesn't do anything, so don't know how to give attributes to the agent or how to move the passenger, within the metro line.Now what it does is leave their pedSourse, and get off at the next station.

Answer (score 0):

When calling any method dealing with connections, your Agent (the person) needs to be connected to those Agents (the stops) first. Your person likely won't be connected to all of them when it's created as connections are either set up by you (by manually connecting the Agents) or the model's environment (by assigning connections based on criteria you define, e.g., random, distance-based, which often don't cover all Agents). If you want to pick a random station, try the following:

`int randomConnecteEstacionIndex = uniform_discr(0, main.estacions.size() - 1);`
`main.estacions.get(randomConnecteEstacionIndex)`

Assuming your stations are stored in the Agent named `Main`, this should get you a random station.